# Problems iterating collection

Tags: backbone.js, collections, iteration

im have the next Model and Collection definition:

```
var Auditoria = Backbone.Model.extend({
   defaults:{
      id: 'undefined',
      user_id: 'undefined',
      user_str: 'undefined',
      user_agent: 'undefined',
      login_from: 'undefined',
      login_date:  'undefined'
   }
});


var AuditoriaList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   model: Auditoria,
   url: $("#ajax-call").val()
});

var sesiones = new AuditoriaList();
sesiones.fetch({
   async: false
});
```

The collection is created correctly, a logging says:

> {length: 15, models: Array[15], _byId: Object, constructor: function,
>   model: function…}

But when try iterate the collection (inside a render view method), apparently, not get correctly the current element:

```
render: function(){
   sesiones.each(function(sesion){
      console.log(sesion);
   }, this);
   return this;
}
```

The console.log, not return models, return:

> {cid: "c1", attributes: Object, collection: r, _changing: false,
>   _previousAttributes: Object…}

Any ideas ?.

Comment: What makes you think `{cid: 'c1', ...}` isn't a model? What do you expect `console.log(sesion)` to put in the console?

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get your model's value, you should iterate collection like this:

```
sesiones.forEach(function(model) {
 console.log(model.get('user_str'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> {cid: "c1", attributes: Object, collection: r, _changing: false, _previousAttributes: Object…}

This is model from your collection

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are expecting to see in your console log is the JSON representation of your model data? Try this:

```
console.log( sesion.toJSON() );
```